# How to access a mapAction method using Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-deployment, vuex

Regards,

I would like to know how I can access the logOut function that comes from mapActions,
What I do not understand is how it is possible, that with the logIn function when I refer to it, it works for me but with the function of logOut no.

Here is the error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: logOut is not defined**

Here I leave the code:

```
 <template>
  <div class="home">
  <v-card height="200px" flat dark app>
  <div class="headline text-xs-center pa-5">
    Active: {{ bottomNav }}
  </div>
  <v-bottom-nav :active.sync="bottomNav" :value="true" absolute color="transparent">
    <v-btn color="teal" flat value="messages">
      <span>Messages</span>
      <v-icon>chat</v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn color="teal" flat value="notifications">
      <span>Notifications</span>
      <v-icon>notifications</v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <v-btn color="red" @click.prevent="logIn()" flat value="logIn">
      <span>LogIn</span>
      <v-icon>whatshot</v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <v-menu offset-y origin="center center" :nudge-bottom="10" transition="scale-transition">
     <v-btn icon large flat slot="activator">
       <v-avatar size="30px">
         <img src="../assets/logo.png" alt="user-logo"/>
       </v-avatar>
     </v-btn>
     <v-list class="pa-0">
       <v-list-tile v-for="(item , index) in items"
          :to="!item.href ? { name: item.name } : null" 
          :href="item.href" 
          @click.prevent="item.click"
          ripple="ripple"
          :disabled="item.disabled" 
          :target="item.target" 
          rel="noopener" 
          :key="index"
          ref="myBtn"
          >
         <v-list-tile-action v-if="item.icon">
           <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
         </v-list-tile-action>
         <v-list-tile-content>
           <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
         </v-list-tile-content>
       </v-list-tile>
     </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </v-bottom-nav>
</v-card>
```

```
<script>
  import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    name: 'home',
    computed: mapState(['data' , 'loading']),
    data(){
      return{
        bottomNav: 'LogIn',
        items: [
          {
             icon: 'account_circle',
             href: '#',
             title: 'Profile',
             click: ''
          },
          {
             icon: 'settings',
             href: '#',
             title: 'Settings',
             click: '' 
          },
          {
             icon: 'fullscreen_exit',
             href: '#',
             title: 'Logout',
             click: () =>{
               this.logOut();
          } 
        }
       ]
  }
},
methods:{
  ...mapActions(['logIn' , 'logOut']),
},
}
 </script>
```

**Actions.js**
Im getting this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined** this error is pointing to the mutation file in the UPDATE_DATA.

```
import { GROUP_ID } from '../config/env';

export const actions = {
logIn({state , commit}){
    FB.login((res) =>{
        console.log(res);
        if(res.status == "connected"){
            state.user.id = res.authResponse.userID;
            state.user.accessToken = res.authResponse.accessToken;

            console.log("user:%s\ntoken:%s" , state.user.id , state.user.accessToken);

            FB.api('/me' , (res) =>{
                this.user.username = res.authResponse.name;
            });

            FB.api(`/${GROUP_ID}/feed`,'GET', (res) =>{
                if(res && !res.error){
                    res['data'].forEach((data) =>{
                        console.log("api connection => " , data);
                        commit('UPDATE_DATA' , data);
                        commit('IS_LOADING_DATA' , false);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
  },{scope:'public_profile, email, groups_access_member_info'});
},
logOut({state}){
    console.log(state.user.accessToken);

    try{
        if(FB.getAccessToken() != null) {
            FB.logout(function(res) {
                console.log("User is logged out");
                console.log(res);
            });
        }else{
            console.log("User is not logged in");
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
}
```

**Mutations.js**

```
export const mutations = {
  UPDATE_DATA({state} , payload){
    state.data = payload;
  },
  IS_LOADING_DATA({state} , payload){
    state.loading = payload;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your store code too, please?

Comment: yea, let me added

Comment: Only visible issue seems arrow function use

Comment: This question is a little confusing with two different errors and no explanation about the second one. If they are independent issues, it would make more sense to make them separate posts.

Comment: Apologies ..
I already solved the problem of the arrow function, but when the user does log-in, he shows me the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Can not set property 'data' of undefined"

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: logOut is not defined
    at Object.click (Home.vue?76f2:83)

Comment: As you seem to have discovered in [your revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53243396/2), the original problem of `logOut` being undefined was due to missing `this` (`logOut()` instead of `this.logOut()`). The new issue you're now observing belongs in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you change to use a non-arrow function in your data `click`, you'll have access to the correct Vue instance. By using an arrow function, `this` is not the Vue instance you're expecting and `this.logOut` will be undefined.

Comment: The only problem I have comes from the file mutations.js especially from UPDATE_DATA, Uncaught TypeError: Can not set property 'data' of undefined

Comment: @ChrisPerez may be open a different question

Comment: @ChrisPerez It might be worth accepting this answer (since it solves the original problem as described in both the post and the title) and opening a new one with a better title and description.